# missing $ inserted in arrays

Tags: errors, pdftex, arrays

this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\clearpage


\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}

\begin{equation*}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2\newline
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
e^{i\pi}=-1\newline
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\pi=\frac{c}{d}\newline\newline
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{d\chi} \int^{\alpha}_{\chi}f(s) ds = f(x)\newline\newline
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(x)\frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\textbf{Ax}=\textbf{b}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\left\|x+y\right\| \leq\left\|x\right\|+\left\|y\right\|
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:solve}
                                \textbf{I}=\begin{pmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}


\vspace{4ex}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:solve}
                                \textbf{I}=\begin{bmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}


\vspace{4ex}
\begin{equation}

                                \textbf{I}=\begin{Bmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{Bmatrix}, 
                                            \begin{vmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{vmatrix},\begin{vmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{vmatrix}


\end{equation}


\end{minipage}
\end{center}


\clearpage



\end{document}
```

I am getting the errors: "Missing $ iserted" and "Display math should end with $$" in lines where arrays are used. I dont seem to understand why this happens.

Comment: Remove the empty lines in the last `equation` environment

Comment: You have blank lines in 63 and 79, remove them, where Bmatrix is.

Comment: but you should never have a blank line before a display math equation, nor follow one display by another, the spacing is al wrong, you are loading `amsmath` that defines several mult-line math displays that could be used here.

Comment: I guess (or hope) this is just a collection of separate formulas, because in general one shouldn't use consecutive equation environments. Don't use `\newline` in `equation`, nor leave blank lines in it. That's all.

Comment: one last thing, how can I get the parenthesis  (3) in the last equation to appear next to the three last matrices?

Answer (score 3):

The immediate cause of the error was the blank line, which is not allowed in display math environments as noted in comments. Also you should never have a blank line before display math, or two display math environments with no text in between. One possible layout would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

First:
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 &= c^2\\
e^{i\pi}&=-1\\
\pi&=\frac{c}{d}
\end{align*}

Second:
\begin{gather*}
\frac{d}{d\chi} \int^{\alpha}_{\chi}f(s)\,ds = f(x)\\[\jot]
\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(x)\frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i
\end{gather*}

Third:
\begin{gather*}
\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}\\
\|x+y\|\leq \|x\|+\|y\|
\end{gather*}

Fourth:
\begin{align}\label{eq:solve}
                                \mathbf{I}&=\begin{pmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{pmatrix}
\\[\jot]
\label{eq:solve2}
                                &=\begin{bmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{bmatrix}
\\[\jot]
\label{eq:solve3}
                               &=\begin{Bmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{Bmatrix}, 
                                            \begin{vmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{vmatrix},\begin{vmatrix}
                                        1&0&0&0\\
                                        0&1&0&0\\
                                        0&0&1&0\\                         
                                        0&0&0&1\\
                                    \end{vmatrix}
\end{align}




\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico done : -)